# Mathematical publications: When to write a variable upright?

Tags: publishing

I hope this is the correct forum. If not, please let me know.

I am writing a master thesis in maths and I am not sure, when I do use upright letters for a variable.

Let's have a look at the following sentence:
Let $a,m$ be naturals and let $\operatorname{g} := \operatorname{lcm}(a,m)$.

My guess is that I write $a$ and $m$ in cursive, because I can choose them arbitrarily. But I would write $\operatorname{g}$ upright, because it is dependent on $a$ and $b$.
In addition, $\operatorname{lcm}$ is an operator, so I write that upright anyways. That's why I would write the $\operatorname{g}$ upright, too.

Is that correct?
Is there a style convention?

Comment: If you're going to publish, the style convention will be up to wherever you're actually publishing. I think you should ask them what their guidelines are.

Comment: In my opinion (it might be wrong), $g$ should be cursive too. I would only write upright in cases like $\mathrm e$ when it is the constant number or the exponential function, $\mathrm d$ for the derivative operator, etc. (and even these things are commonly written in cursive).

Comment: You can use any font you like in your thesis if it is consistent. If you want to write $g$ in cursive, upright, or in any other font is up to you.

Comment: Also, another example of a similar case, we usually write $f(x) = \sin (x)$ with a cursive $f$.

Answer (score 2):

In any style convention I ever was aware of you would write $g$ in your example cursive.

The letters $\operatorname{lcm}$ are upright as a multi-letter operator name.

In fact, in your source code you have written

```
$\operatorname{g} := \operatorname{lcm}(a,m)$
```

You would normally just write

```
$g := \operatorname{lcm}(a,m)$
```

So, if you are using LaTeX for your thesis, the question is more or less handled automatically, if you put all your math into `$...$` and use `\operatorname` when needed.

Comment: Thank you. I can understand, but I can't follow the logic, since I abbreviate an upright operator (lcm) with a cursive letter (g).
So I have to get used to this style, but at least I have a good opinion from you. Thanks for that!

Comment: I would look at it as follows: $g$ is not the operator, but the result of the operator applied to some variables, and therefore a variable itself.

Comment: Is your thesis in math or computer science, btw? Maybe there are different conventions in CS.

Comment: In math. I will add this information in the post.

Comment: BTW, a good reference for style questions is https://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf

Comment: Wow, thank you! I will have a look at that! And thanks for your comment "g is not the operator". This was very helpful!